# Azure DevOps Pipelines fails when using ReadyToRun

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

We're currently trying to publish a .NET project in DevOps in Release Mode with **ReadyToRun** enabled that refers to some artifacts located in another project (Our shared library).

The problem is that each time we run the *dotnet publish* command, it throws a whole bunch of 401 authorization errors like seen below:

[image]

What is really **important** to mention is that this issue **DOES NOT OCCOUR** when publishing as **Debug** or without **ReadyToRun**.

Microsoft has not been able to help us, and keep pointing out, that there must be an authorization issue since it is giving us a 401. But that doesn't really make sense, when it apparently works fine without ReadyToRun, meaning that it can retreive the artifacts succesfully.

This is the pipeline that we are currently using:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  publish.buildConfiguration: 'Publish'
  publish.path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\publish\'
  publish.artifactFolderName : 'Packages'
  
  #App API
  projectName.appApi: 'Linak.Deskline.Tracking.AppApi'
  projectPath.appApi: '.\Sources\Linak.Deskline.Tracking\Linak.Deskline.Tracking.AppApi\$(projectName.appApi).csproj'
  ressource.dev.function.appApi: 'func-dtr-app-weu-dev-01'
  ressource.tst.function.appApi: 'func-dtr-app-weu-tst-01'
  ressource.prod.function.appApi: 'func-dtr-app-weu-prod-01'

  #Integrator API
  projectName.integratorApi: 'Linak.Deskline.Tracking.integratorApi'
  projectPath.integratorApi: '.\Sources\Linak.Deskline.Tracking\Linak.Deskline.Tracking.IntegratorApi\$(projectName.integratorApi).csproj'
  ressource.dev.function.integratorApi: 'func-dtr-integrator-weu-dev-01'
  ressource.tst.function.integratorApi: 'func-dtr-integrator-weu-tst-01'
  ressource.prod.function.integratorApi: 'func-dtr-integrator-weu-prod-01'

  #LipDataHandler Api
  projectName.lipDataHandler: 'Linak.Deskline.Tracking.LipDataHandler'
  projectPath.lipDataHandler: '.\Sources\Linak.Deskline.Tracking\Linak.Deskline.Tracking.LipDataHandler\$(projectName.lipDataHandler).csproj'  
  ressource.dev.function.lipDataHandler: 'func-dtr-lipevents-weu-dev-01'
  ressource.tst.function.lipDataHandler: 'func-dtr-lipevents-weu-tst-01'
  ressource.prod.function.lipDataHandler: 'func-dtr-lipevents-weu-prod-01'

stages: 
- stage: Build
  jobs: 
  - job: BuildAndPublishZips
    displayName: Build and publish zip files
    steps:
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Get Nuget'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Nuget Restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: '.\Sources\Linak.Deskline.Tracking\nuget.config'
        arguments: '--runtime win-x86'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build and publish - $(projectName.appApi)'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '$(projectPath.appApi)'
        arguments: '-o $(publish.path) /bl -c $(publish.buildConfiguration)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build and publish - $(projectName.integratorApi) '
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '$(projectPath.integratorApi)'
        arguments: '-o $(publish.path) /bl -c $(publish.buildConfiguration)'
      
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build and publish - $(projectName.lipDataHandler)'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '$(projectPath.lipDataHandler)'
        arguments: '-o $(publish.path) /bl -c $(publish.buildConfiguration)'
      
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Run tests'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: '**\*.csproj'
        testRunTitle: 'Deskline Cloud Test'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publishing deploy packages'
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(publish.path)'
        artifact: '$(publish.artifactFolderName)'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

#DEV
- stage: Deploy_DEV
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs: 
  - deployment: Deploy_DEV
    displayName: 'Deploy to DEV'
    environment: 'Tracking - DEV'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps: 
          - task: PowerShell@2  
            displayName: "List build artifacts"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                Write-Host "cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)"
                cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)
                dir   
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy DEV - $(projectName.integratorApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Development'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.dev.function.integratorApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.integratorApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy DEV - $(projectName.appApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Development'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.dev.function.appApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.appApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy DEV - $(projectName.lipDataHandler)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Development'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.dev.function.lipDataHandler)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.lipDataHandler).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
#TEST
- stage: Deploy_TEST
  dependsOn: 'Deploy_DEV'
  jobs: 
  - deployment: Deploy_TEST
    displayName: Deploy to TEST
    environment: 'Tracking - TEST'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps: 
          - task: PowerShell@2  
            displayName: "List build artifacts"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host "cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)"
                cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)
                dir   
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy TEST - $(projectName.integratorApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Test'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.tst.function.integratorApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.integratorApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy TEST - $(projectName.appApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Test'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.tst.function.appApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.appApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy DEV - $(projectName.lipDataHandler)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Test'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.tst.function.lipDataHandler)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.lipDataHandler).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
#PROD
- stage: Deploy_PROD
  dependsOn: 'Deploy_TEST'
  jobs: 
  - deployment: Deploy_PROD
    displayName: Deploy to PROD
    environment: 'Tracking - PROD'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps: 
          - task: PowerShell@2  
            displayName: "List build artifacts"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host "cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)"
                cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)
                dir   
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy PROD - $(projectName.integratorApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Production'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.prod.function.integratorApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.integratorApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy PROD - $(projectName.appApi)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Production'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.prod.function.appApi)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.appApi).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy PROD - $(projectName.lipDataHandler)'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Deskline Cloud - Production'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: $(ressource.prod.function.lipDataHandler)
              package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/$(publish.artifactFolderName)/$(projectName.lipDataHandler).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

It fails in the following step:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build and publish - $(projectName.appApi)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(projectPath.appApi)'
    arguments: '-o $(publish.path) /bl -c $(publish.buildConfiguration)'
```

We've already tried different things, such as:

1. Adding -no-restore to the publish command
2. Adding this part to the pipeline:

   steps:

   - task: UseDotNet@2
     displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.x'
     inputs:
     version: 6.0.x
3. Ensured that the build service where the authorization fails, has access to the artifacts in the shared library

[image]

Microsoft has already had 10 people on the case now, and I don't feel like we are going nowhere. So I thought, maybe someone in here has a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to build your projects before 'publish'?

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ BuildConfiguration }}'
```

Comment: Just tried that, and it fails as well :(